# How to pass data to Excel sheet from string builder values

Tags: c#, excel

I've got data from string builder and I want to copy that data to Excel. Here is what I've tried:

```
StringBuilder result1 = new StringBuilder();                                       
xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("DeliveryItem");
for (i = 0; i <= xmlnode.Count - 1; i++)
{                     
   result1.AppendLine(xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(3).InnerText.Trim());
}
string delivery_name = result1.ToString();

xlapp.Visible = true;
xlapp.DisplayAlerts = false;
workbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;
worksheet.Name = "Delivery_report";
worksheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Name";
```

How do I copy the data from string builder to cell *A2:A500* ?

Comment: why not use a list and loop through the list getting the index to identify the cell index using the index in the forloop.

Comment: But I'm in need of string builder for other purpose

Comment: in that case `result1.ToString().Split(Environment.NewLine)` could do the trick with which you get the array and do the same logic as above. But a `String.Join(Environment.NewLine,list)` also might help if you go with a list!

Comment: I've already used resul1.AppendLine for that,but how do i copy the data from string builder to excel column?